# Generic interface with extends generic of Enums

Tags: java

I am trying to write a generic Event System. For this I'd like to create an Interface for the `EventHandler` like this *(which does not works)*:

```
public interface GameEventHandler<I extends GameEvent<TYPE extends Enum<?>, ATT extends Enum<?>>> {
    public void handleEvent(final GameEvent<TYPE, ATT>... e);
    public void registerListener(final GameEventListener<I> listener,
            final TYPE... type);
    public void unregisterListener(final GameEventListener<I>... listener);
    public void unregisterAllListener();
    public void unregisterAllListener(final I... type);
    public void processEvents();
    public void processEvents(final int maxTimeInMS);
}
```

But this does not work as I *think* it should.

The Event itself is a Generic Element which is pretty simple:

```
public class GameEvent<T extends Enum<?>, S extends Enum<?>> {
    private HashMap<S, String> values;
    private T type;

    public void init(T type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void addMessage(S t, String value) {
        this.values.put(t, value);
    }

    public void getMessage(S t) {
        this.values.get(t);
    }
}
```

If I implement the `HandlerInterface` I'd like to have it still be generic so there is something like a `DefaultHandler<GameEvent<TypeEnum, AttributEnum>>()` to create it. So you can use the Interface to create your own handler or use the `DefaultHandler` which I provide but still can use your own Enums.

At the moment I am able to create the interface like this:

```
public interface GameEventHandler<I extends GameEvent<TYPE, ATT>, TYPE extends Enum<?>,     ATT extends Enum<?>>
```

But I don't get the Implementation of an DefaultHandler Generic

```
public class DefaultGameEventHandler implements GameEventHandler<GameEvent<EventTypes,      AttributeTypes>, EventTypes, AttributeTypes>
```

// not generic those are testing Enums
So what an I doing wrong? Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep it simple. `I` is a `GameEvent<TYPE, ATT>` which can be entirely deducted from `TYPE` and `ATT`. So I'd just remove `I` and write:

```
public interface GameEventHandler<TYPE extends Enum<?>, ATT extends Enum<?>> {
    public void handleEvent(final GameEvent<TYPE, ATT>... e);
    public void registerListener(final GameEventListener<TYPE, ATT> listener,
                                 final TYPE... type);
    public void unregisterListener(final GameEventListener<TYPE, ATT>... listener);
    public void unregisterAllListener();
    public void unregisterAllListener(final GameEvent<TYPE, ATT>... type);
    public void processEvents();
    public void processEvents(final int maxTimeInMS);
}

public class GameEventListener<TYPE extends Enum<?>, ATT extends Enum<?>> { }
public enum EventTypes {}
public enum AttributeTypes {}

public class DefaultGameEventHandler
               implements GameEventHandler<EventTypes, AttributeTypes> {

}
```